# Conga and Matrix Report

Tags: reporting, conga

I generating report from Salesforce to be used in Conga Compose.The report that I created in Salesforce is in  Matrix Format but as we know it got [limitation](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kckyAAA) where it wont show the column that does not contain data.Example if I got data for year 2014,2012,2011 but no data for 2013 it will display like this

> 2014 2012 2011
>   -----   -------   ---- 
>   xxx      xxxx     xxx

Instead of

> 2014 2013  2012 2011
>   -----   -------   ----  ------- 
>   xxx      -        xxxx     xxx

How I can make it display in Conga powerpoint slide with or without data properly?If there any workaround to show no data column?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question - I'm a Product Marketing Specialist here at Conga.  I encourage you to log a case with our support team to get the best answer to your question (http://congasphere.com/live-support.html), but here's a way you might approach this:

Even a SOQL query that uses and groups by a CALENDAR_YEAR date function will skip years where there is no data.  Conga Composer also doesn't support matrix report types.  To work around these limitations, you could create distinct queries (or reports, if you prefer) that filter specifically for each calendar year.  Example:

> SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CloseDate) =
>   2014
>
> SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CloseDate)
>   = 2013

etc.

Conga Composer can merge a field from multiple data sets (it supports up to 50 reports or queries in a single solution) onto a single slide of a PPTX template using this technique: http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kbdetail.aspx?kbid=132

So if you were to create distinct queries for each calendar year you're looking to span in your report, you could merge the data from each into specific locations on a slide in your PPTX template.  The only limitation would be that any blank years would return a null value, so instead of a dash for years with no records, your output could look something like this:

[image]

I hope this helps get you pointed in the right direction, but please do give our support team a call if we can help any further.  Sometimes a screen share is much easier for tackling problems like this!  Thanks very much.

-Robert